# Number of ways possible to form a number?

Tags: permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

Suppose we need to form a 4 digit number with the restriction that

```
At 1000th place only : 3 5 7 can come
At 100th place only  : 8 9 3 can come
At 10th place only   : 6 8 9 can come
At unit place        : 5 3 8 can come
```

and also no two places can have same digit so 3365 is invalid but 3865 is perfectly valid. And can it be generalized for a n digit number with n places having m different options. 
Edit : Numbers on each place are distinct that is if at unit place 5 3 8 has come than they cannot come again so 5 3 8 3 is invalid(this is for generalization.)

Comment: For $n>10$ the answer is $0$.

Comment: And it greatly depends on the distribution of the digits. If you had to choose from $1,2,3$ in every place of a $4$-digit number, then you'd get zero, as well, but there are cases where $m=3$ and $n=4$ where there are such numbers. So it is not merely a function of $m,n$.

Comment: The easiest way to count may be simply to generate all 81 combinations systematically and reject those that have repeated digits.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can it not be done by inclusion-exclusion principle . Like total numbers = 81-(3(Numbers with 3 thrice))-(3c2*9)+9)(subtract numbers having 3 twice and thrice so)...I am not able to extend it.Its getting complex.

Comment: @user1879548 I didn't say it couldn't be done, only that the result wasn't a function of only $m,n$.

Answer (score 0):

For your main question, I don't see anything easier than counting.  There are only $3^4=81$ possibilities before you enforce the no duplicates, so try them all. For the generalization, it feels like it should be NP-complete, very similar to 3-SAT, which says there will (probably) not be anything easy.

Comment: I think the problem is solvable using inclusion-exclusion principle.. 81-((3)-(3c2*9)+9)(Excluding numbers having twice and thrice 3).(unable to extend it furthur)

Comment: @user1879548:  there are also the constraints from $8$'s and $9$'s, which interact with the $3$'s.  Because there isn't a clear structure to the repeats, I think you just have to count.